# alternative to if statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am curious to see any alternative(s) to the regular if statements such as

```
if(x)
     do a;
if(y)
     do b;
if(z)
    do c;
```

so as you see all if statements are seperate and no else condition. Please notice that X Y Z are totally seperate conditions so switch wouldn't fit.

Comment: While curiosity might be humorous ... why would I want an alternative to if, especially when a condition is that switch doesn't fit? As if Java wasn't bloated enough already...

Comment: either what you are trying to do is silly (if's are great!), or you need to give more information. i can imagine a situation where code like this could be handled with a messaging pattern or something else that is interesting (provided that your situation is not as simple as you explained it).

Comment: What do you expect this alternative to provide that the presented code cannot? (less characters, more readability?)

Comment: well I am just exploring, I know "if"statement is elegant and easy to read but extra knowledge never hurts :)

Comment: @Hellnar: There's extra knowledge that has value, and there's obscure code golf junk.

Comment: in large enough quantity, `if` statements are poisonous

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One "truely object oriented" answer would be to define an interface for "Rule" (with condition() and action() methods), create 3 implementations, stuff them into a collection, and then just iterate through them generically as in:

```
List<Rule> rules = .... ; // your 3 rules initialized here somehow
for(Rule r : rules) {
  if(r.condition()) {
    r.action();
  }
}
```

This makes a lot more sense if you have 300 rules/conditions rather than just 3.

*In Java8, you may want to do this instead, if the rules are CPU-intensive:*

```
rules.parallelStream().filter(Rule::condition).forEach(Rule::action);
```

Comment: You could use a Map for O(1) time, rather than O(n).

Comment: A Map won't work here, because the condition is unique to each Rule implementation. Map requires an actual key, not some code buried in a callable method.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is yes.

There are a few time you can avoid using if for conditional evluation and branching all together.
And they have moments of appropriateness.

1. Polymorphism, when behavior is dependent on the initial values
2. Referrenced Assignment, when you know the possible initial values and they have 1 to 1 correlation with the return values. Lists are better than arrays for this, but...

   > ```
   > // Example:  
   > if (a==1) { b=2;  }  
   > if (a==2) { b=17; }  
   >
   > // Becomes  
   > int fx(2);  // our array of answers  
   > fx[0] = 2;   
   > fx[1] = 17;  
   > b = fx[ a - 1 ];
   > ```
3. Referrenced Branching, when you know the possible initial values and they have 1 to 1 correlation with the function/branch to use.  (example not Java)

   > ```
   > // Example:
   > if (a==1) { doSomething1();  }  
   > if (a==2) { doSomething2(); }  
   >
   > // Becomes
   > function * fx(2);  // our array or better still, list of functions  
   > fx[0] = &doSomething1;   
   > fx[1] = &doSomething2;  
   > `fx[ a - 1 ](); `
   > ```
4. Direct boolean assignment.

   We hate:

   > ```
   > if (thisCondition == true) {  
   >   b = true;  
   > } else {  
   >   b = false;  
   > }
   > ```

   Should be:

   > b = thisCondition;

Answer (score 6):

The alternatives to `if-else` in Java are the switch statement and the [conditional ternary](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (**?:**) operator, neither of which do exactly what you're asking (handle just an `if` with no `else`).  The code you posted is the best way to do it, in my opinion.

Comment: Multiple conditions in Ternary : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548857/multiple-conditions-in-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 4):

Use polymorphism.

```
interface SomethingDoer {
    public void doSomething();
}

class ADoer implements SomethingDoer { ... }
class BDoer implements SomethingDoer { ... }
class CDoer implements SomethingDoer { ... }

public class Main {
     public static void main (String[] args) {
          SomethingDoer doer = new SomethingDoerFactory(args).getDoer();
          doer.doSomething();
     }
}
```

The if is not completely eliminated, but it is moved to SomethingDoerFactory. This solution is not applicable in all cases, but in some of them it is a very good alternative to multiple ifs.

Here is a nice talk about it:
http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/08/clean-code-talks-inheritance-polymorphism-testing/

Comment: Any comments on why you downvote? Isn't it an alternative? Or isn't it good enough to be mentioned?

Comment: I'd only consider a polymorphic solution if my conditional was already based on **type**.  I wouldn't create an entire class hierarchy just to replace `if(x) do a;`

Comment: if many cases this makes sense. see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc - google tech talks. (The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing) i consider the downvote wrong.

Comment: Direct from Misko's slides: "sometimes an <code>if</code> is just an <code>if</code>".  Unless you re-use these if statements in a lot of places, this is going to make things needlessly complex.  Also: your solution is incomplete.  What if both conditions x and y hold? You have missed AAndBDoer, AAndCDoer, BAndCDoer, AAndBAndCDoer; these are well-covered by the original code.

Comment: Obviously this depends on exactly what it means to "do a". Polymorphism might well be an excellent solution, but the example is simply too generic to have a single solution for all cases. AAndBDoer etc are typically solved by using Decorator/Composition patterns for a polymorphism-type solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is the most simple, **readable yet effective** solution. I would be surprised to see effective alternatives here.

EDIT

you can try to apply **extract method** several times:

```
doAIfX();
doBIfY();
doCifZ();
```

where methods are defined by:

```
void doAIfX() {
    if (!X) {
        return;
    }

    // do 'a'
}
```

Comment: I do this in firmware for a device that can have many different options enabled or disabled.  I'd rather have my main() call things like doFooIfEnabled() than clutter it up with lots of ifs and #ifdefs.

Comment: Like any pattern, there are times when it should be used, and times when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this, Implement Enum based on condition and call override method.

```
public enum Rule{
            a(){
            @Override
            public void do(){
            // do something.
            }
            },
            b(){
            @Override
            public void do(){
            // do something.
            }
            },
            c(){
            @Override
            public void do(){
            // do something.
            }


            public abstract void do();

            }
        }




     public class Test{
            public static void main(String[] args){
                Rule r = Rule.valueOf("a");
                r.do();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what x, y, z and a, b, c are. Sometimes if statements are more suitable. Sometimes polymorphism is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have these if statements somewhere.

They can be refactored into other methods to keep the present method clean, as others have suggested.  If you need to re-use this same **set** of if statements in a number of places, it **might** be possible use the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a perfect case for using **closure**. But for that you need **groovy** or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

How about...
myAnimator(thing, pos, speed | computeSpeed());

if speed === *undefined* it will then computeSpeed... I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's really depends on the context... but yeah if-else is only one of *control flow* statement in java:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html