# Multiple conditions in ternary conditional operator?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I am taking my first semester of Java programming, and we've just covered the conditional operator (? :) conditions. I have two questions which seem to be wanting me to "nest" conditional operators within eachother, something that I could easily (yet tediously) do with if-else-if statements.

1) "Assume that month is an  int variable whose value is 1 or 2 or 3 or 5 ... or 11 or 12. Write an expression whose value is "jan" or "feb" or "mar" or "apr" or "may" or "jun" or "jul" or "aug" or "sep" or "oct" or "nov" or "dec" based on the value of  month. (So, if the value of  month were 4 then the value of the expression would be "apr".)."

an idea I had looks something like this:

```
(month==1)?"jan":(month==2)?"feb": (month==3)?"mar": (month==4)?"apr": 
(month==5)?"may":(month==6)?"jun": (month==7)?"jul":(month==8)?"aug":
(month==9)?"sep": (month==10)?"oct": (month==11)?"nov": (month==12)?"dec":
```

(I know this isn't a complete expression, but I'm not sure how to phrase the operator to handle so many conditions.)

2) Assume that  credits is an  int variable whose value is 0 or positive. Write an expression whose value is "freshman" or "sophomore" or "junior" or "senior" based on the value of  credits. In particular: if the value of  credits is less than 30 the expression's value is "freshman"; 30-59 would be a "sophomore", 60-89 would be "junior" and 90 or more would be a "senior".

again, I've been toying around and the best I can come up with is something like(and I'm probs missing some necessary parentheses):

```
credits < 30 ? "freshman": credits >= 30 && <=59 ?
 "sophomore": credits >= 60 && <= 89 ? "junior": "senior"
```

I've Googled around and checked the database here, but I don't THINK that there's anything exactly like this question; forgive me if I'm wrong. The program (CodeLab) won't take Switch-Case or the if-else-if solution, always suggesting I should be using the conditional ? : operator, but everywhere I've looked I haven't figured out how to rig the operator to handle so many conditions. We aren't far past this in the book, so if you guys could help me find a solution, it'd be great if it's one that jives with the little bit I've learned so far.

Comment: Consider that if `credits` isn't < 30, it's always going to be >= 30, so that condition is pointless.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For the **first** question, you *can* indeed use the ternary operator, but a simpler solution would be to use a `String[]` with the month descriptions, and then subscript this array:

```
String[] months = { "jan", "feb", "mar", ... };
int month = 1; // jan
String monthDescription = months[month - 1]; // arrays are 0-indexed
```

Now, for your **second** question, the ternary operator seems more appropriate since you have fewer conditions, although an `if` would be much easier to read, imho:

```
String year = "senior";
if (credits < 30) {
  year = "freshman";
} else if (credits <= 59) {
  year = "sophomore";
} else if (credits <= 89) {
  year = "junior";
}
```

Contrast this with the ternary operator:

```
String year = credits < 30 ? "freshman" : credits <= 59 ? "sophomore" : credits <= 89 ? "junior" : "senior";
```

Comment: I agree about the second question, the if is easier to read. The ternary operator option was correct, but I'm still having trouble on the first one. I'm confused on how to use the ternary operator; can I use month == 1...? Once again all I have is  month == 1  ? "jan" : month == 2 ? "feb" : month == 3 ? "mar" : month == 4 ? "apr" : month == 5 ? "may" : month == 6 ? "jun" : month == 7 ? "jul" : month == 8 ? "aug" : month == 9 ? "sep" : month == 10 ? "oct" : month == 11 ? "nov" : month == 12 ? "dec"    I don't understand the explanation with arrays, we haven't discussed those yet.

Comment: @EvanWelser: You can yes, that is correct. Your last condition can be simplified to `month == 11 ? "nov" : "dec"`. No need to explicitly test `month == 12`.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at your answer to 2, that's what I ended up trying. It actually wouldn't accept the specific condition "month ==12", it HAD to be month == 11 ? "nov" : "dec" but I'm not sure why the 12-specific condition wasn't accepted by the program. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EvanWelser: You're welcome! That's because if you had `"nov" : month == 12 ? "dec"`, you were missing the *third* part of the last ternary condition, that is, the case where month is greater than 12. You'd have to add for example `"nov" : month == 12 ? "dec" : "invalid month"`.

Answer (score 16):

Parentheses are like violence: if it's not working, use more.

But seriously:

```
( condition A ? value A :
  ( condition B ? value B : 
    ( condition C ? value C :
       ...
    )
  )
)
```

And please, don't ever write code like that for anything important.

Comment: But still, knowing of the operators precedence and order of evaluation - is a good thing. :)

Comment: I agree, and if it weren't an online homework question I could probably answer it with much more readability. I used the parentheses and they seemed to have helped. Thank you

Comment: I upvoted just for that little fun sentence in the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

`(month==1)?"jan":(month==2)?"feb": (month==3)?"mar": (month==4)?"apr": 
(month==5)?"may":(month==6)?"jun": (month==7)?"jul":(month==8)?"aug":
(month==9)?"sep": (month==10)?"oct": (month==11)?"nov": (month==12)?"dec":null`

you got it right, the only thing you need is the null at the end when you finish thats all.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question at my study. Thanks for the info about `if` and `else`. Would be my choice too except the assignment is asking us specificly to use the conditional operators. so basically they're asking us to write it in an unreadable way.

```
(credits < 30) ? "freshman" : (credits >= 30 && credits < 60) ?"sophomore" : (credits >= 60 && credits < 90) ? "junior" : "senior"
```

This was mine and its correct. I am wondering though if  there is a shorter piece of code  (using only the conditional operators.).

By the way Evan your code was almost good. just missed some brackets around each expression.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in brackets and add null at the end and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

You are handling the idea of a if-else-if situation in a ternary correctly, but your syntax was slightly off (as you said it might be).

I would, however, change it slightly so that extra conditions aren't checked unnecessarily.

```
String year = credits < 30 ? "freshman": credits <= 59
       ? "sophomore": credits <= 89 ? "junior" : "senior";
```

But your best option is just to use if and else statements for the sake of code readability.

Answer (score 1):

-In my case, I have an **"isloadingMakePayment"** flag based on the flag I have to implement **Loading bar** over That Tag.It means when **isloadingMakePayment** is true tag show **"Loading Data..."** instead. Implemented multiple conditions.

-An **"isPolicyRename"** is also a flag that I used for inside condition.MeanWhile **"renamePolicy"** is variable which contain some value that I use to show over HTML page

- Simply use this pattern :

`<a class="btn btn-orange" (click)="onMakePayment()"> <span *ngIf="isloadingMakePayment"><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>Loading Data...</span>{{isloadingMakePayment ? '' : isPolicyRename 'Make Payment to ' + renamePolicy : 'Make Payment' }} </a>`

---

Thank you.