# Access HashMap methods with user input String instead of HashMap name

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, user-input

I have two HashMaps `HashMap<String, String> verb` and `HashMap<String, String> noun`. I need to access their Keys and Values using user input stored in `String name`. How can I access HashMaps so that I don't have to explicitly state the name of the HashMap in my code?

Suppose a user creates `HashMap<String, String> adjective`, the method should handle a HashMap isn't explicitly named in the code. I thought of trying something like `name.get(question)` instead of `noun.get(question)` or `verb.get(question)` but obviously that's not possible. I want to make my code more efficient so that users can access a HashMap that is not 'verb' or 'noun'.

I've tried looking through the given methods for Strings, but nothing really fits. I haven't had much luck finding other threads that address this either.

```
if(name.contains("verb")) {
    for(String question: verb.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(question);
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        hold = reader.nextLine();
        if(hold.equals(verb.get(question))) {
            System.out.println("CORRECT");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("INCORRECT");
        }
    }
} 
else if(name.contains("noun")) {
    for(String question : noun.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(question);
        hold = reader.nextLine();
        if(hold.equals(noun.get(question))) {
            System.out.println("CORRECT");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("INCORRECT");
        }
    }
}
else { System.out.println("not a set"); }

return "";
```

Right now, everything prints as expected for verb and noun. The key prints, the other user input stored in `String hold` is compared to the value associated with the key, and prints if correct or not before going to the next key in the HashMap.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to guess the type and content of variables like `name`, `verb`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Update the question with types of noun, verb and name.
I'm assuming as per my understanding, you have two maps which have some elements in them.

```
Map<String, String> verb;
Map<String, String> noun;
```

To optimize the above code. Create a method as below

```
private static void check(Map<String, String> map) {
   if(map != null){
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       map.forEach((key, value) -> {
          System.out.println(key);
          String hold = reader.nextLine();
          System.out.println(( hold.equals(value) ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT" ));
       });
   } else {
       System.out.println("not a set");
   }
}
```

And call this method as below

```
this.check(name.contains("verb") ? verb:name.contains("noun") ? noun : null);
```

Explanation : 
   While calling check() method we are passing map based on the value of name. The map can be verb, noun or NULL.

If you don't know how conditional operator works, please find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548857/multiple-conditions-in-ternary-conditional-operator)